# Constraint in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, constraints

We have table `Person(Id, Name, Type)` and `Role(Id, Name`) and a binding `M:N` table `Person_Role(Person_Id, Role_Id)` which means "a person can have set of roles".

All we want to do is to have a UNIQUE constraint in MS SQL 2008 R2 which holds uniqueness of

`(Person.Name, Person.Type, Person.SetOfRoles)`. That is `(Jack, 1, {A,B})` and `(Jack, 1, {B})` are NOT duplicities.

If we could use Oracle's pre-insert triggers, it would solve everything.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** We use MS SQL with Entity Framework and we DO NOT have the exact insert SQL command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INSTEAD OF TRIGGER in Sql Server.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on Role
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Role
       -- Your logic goes here
       FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: Great, thank you, but we use MS SQL with Entity Framework and WE DO NOT have exact insert SQL. What then???

Comment: You know the structure of your tables so you know how the `inserted` table looks like. You said yourself that you can do it in Oracle. Or use a stored proc that takes all the data and contains the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger
Example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ryanw/archive/2006/02/02/437242.aspx